# How to increase the width of an AngularJS Material datepicker

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have something like this:

[image: Screenshot of 2 inputs (A "Date of recruitment" date picker input and a "months" input)]

How is it possible to make the line under the "Date of recruitment" and the "down array" adapt to half of the layout as in flex="50" for example. It is pretty easy for normal input fields.

Current markup:

```
<md-content layout-padding> 
 <form> 
  <div layout-gt-xs="row"> 
   <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs> 
      <label> date </label> 
      <md-datepicker ng-model="cv.contract.dateOfRecruitment"></md-datepicker> 
   </md-input-container>
   <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs> 
      <label> months </label> 
          <input required ng-model="cv.contract.months" ng-pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]*$/" /> 
   </md-input-container> 
  </div>
 </form> 
</md-content>
```

Comment: Can you share the markup you are using currently please

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have added the markup to the question.

Answer (score 1):

See these tickets:

- https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9550
- https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9483

This feature won't be implemented due to layout troubles. But there's a workaround solution described [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9550)

Answer (score 1):

There is no official documentation. You could consider using custom CSS.

Try to add `width: 100%` to the container of the date picker. It will increase width certainly. Of course, it assumes that the parent container of date picker is divided by half-width(50%) each other.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this property as `!important` worked for me

```
mat-form-field {
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the datepicker:

```
<input class="md-datepicker-input md-input" id="input_58" size="50">
```